# Regex Multiple Lookaheads and Word Exclusion

Tags: javascript, regex

I am close to where I want to be on this. Javascript Regex: I need to match words that only start with numbers, aren't certain reserved words ('in','between','and','or') and aren't contained in quotes. I am almost there I just can't seem to figure out how to negate my reserved words. It is probably obvious this is part of a SQL validation and I'm picking out fields names to validate them in a separate routine. I could easily strip them using multiple expressions but thought I'd make an academic effort and try it this way.
Here's where I'm at. Help, suggestions, improvements and explanations all appreciated.

```
       \(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)+([A-z][0-9A-z][^\s\=\>\<\)\(]*)\gi
```

Here are some test cases:

```
(THIS >= CURRENTBORROWERBALANCE) [match CURRENTBORROWERBALANCE]
(THIS = 'anything') [match THIS]
(THIS BETWEEN '2007-01-01' and '2010-01-01') [match THIS]
```

and a link to test cases and update regex: http://regexr.com/3aq57

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Don't parse languages (including SQL) with JS.

Comment: @torazaburo: There's nothing wrong with parsing them in JS, if only the parser is proper. You probably meant "*don't parse complex languages (including SQL) with a single regex*"

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)\b(?!and\b|in\b|between\b)[a-zA-Z]\w+` with `global` and `case-insensitive` modifiers.

You can add any reserved word to `(?!and\b|in\b|between\b)` (don't forget the boundary)

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH2rH3/1).